# alloy: What's wrong with this Alloy code?

Tags: alloy

how to solve this problem of execute this alloy code?
tested with alloy v 4.1
give us an error:

.error type
This cannot be a legal relational join where
left hand side is t (type = {this/Target})
right hand side is this/subjects (type = {this/subjects})

```
sig Element{}
sig policy extends Element{}
sig Target extends Element{}
sig Targets extends Target{}
abstract sig subjects,Request,Action extends Targets{}
sig Rule{}
sig Attribute{}
sig Value{}
sig Effect{}
sig T1,T2,T3 extends Target{}
sig SUB1,SUB2,SUB3 extends subjects{}
sig elementMatch{}
abstract sig Policy{
policyTarget : one Target ,
rules : set Rule ,
}
abstract sig Elements{
attributes : Attribute -> Value}
{attributes in values}

pred targetMatch[t:Target,r:Request]
{
some s:t.subjects | elementMatch[s, r.subject]
some s:t. resources| elementMatch[s,r.resource]
some s:t. actions| elementMatch[s,r.action]
}
fun ruleResponse [r:Rule,req:Request]
:Effect{
if targetMatch[r.ruleTarget,req]
then r.ruleEffect
}
assert permitforprofessor{
all q : Request{
{~(q.subject.attributes).Attribute=professor}
=> policyResponse[p,q] = permit}
}
run targetMatch
```

Comment: Why the anonymous downvote? It's a reasonable question.

Comment: Certainly because the author of this question fails to show any real effort in trying to solve the problem himself.

Answer (score 3):

I did not go that much into the detail of your code, and yet I can see many flaws.

The error you received is due to the `t.subject` you wrote in the targetMatch predicate.

Everything is written in the error message. This is not a legal relational join.

Amongst other errors,  elementMatch[s, r.subject] also looks highly suspicious knowing that elementMatch is declared as a signature.

I advise you to go through the online Alloy tutorial to get more familiar with the language:

http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/online/frame-FS-1.html